# Extract a Sentence Containing a Word Using Python... As well as the sentences around it?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, text-segmentation

There are a bunch of questions that get at extracting a particular sentence that contains a word (like [extract a sentence using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001800/extract-a-sentence-using-python) and [Python extract sentence containing word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032832/python-extract-sentence-containing-word)), and I have enough beginner experience with NLTK and SciPy to be able to do that on my own.

However, I'm getting stuck trying to extract a sentence containing a word... as well as the sentences before and after the target sentence.

For example:

"I was walking along to school the other day, when it began to rain. I reached for my umbrella, but I realized I had forgotten it at home. What could I do? I immediately ran for the nearest tree. But then I realized I couldn't stay try with a tree without any leaves."

In this example, the target word is "could." If I wanted to extract the target sentence (*What could I do?*) as well as the preceding and following sentences (*I reached for my umbrella, but I realized I had forgotten it at home.* and *I immediately ran for the nearest tree.*), what would be a good approach?

Assume I have each paragraph sectioned off as its own text...

```
for paragraph in document:
    do something
```

... is there a proper way to tackle this question? I have about 10,000 paragraphs with varying numbers of sentences around the target word (which appears is every single paragraph).

Comment: Have you extracted the sentences from each paragraph into a list (one list item per sentence)?

Comment: Do you need to find *every* occurrence of the target word in a paragraph, or just the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
for paragraph in document:
    paragraph_sentence_list = tokenizer.tokenize(paragraph)
    for line in xrange(0,len(paragraph_sentence_list)):
        if 'could' in paragraph_sentence_list[line]:

            print(paragraph_sentence_list[line])

            try:
                print(paragraph_sentence_list[line-1])
            except IndexError as e:
                print('Edge of paragraph. Beginning.')
                pass

            try:
                print(paragraph_sentence_list[line+1])
            except IndexError as e:
                print('Edge of paragraph. End.')
                pass
```

What this does is break the paragraphs into a list of sentences.

The iterating over the sentences tests if 'could' is in the setence. If it is, then it prints the previous index [line-1], the current index [line] and the next index [line+1]

Comment: Perhaps with `try:/except: IndexError` around the prev/next line print statements to handle edge cases?

Comment: how is using NLTK splitter better than `split('. ')`?

Comment: @user1993 it has some extra helpers  http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/api.html#StringTokenizer.tokenize but otherwise it's about the same.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of `sent_tokenize` to extract sentences from raw corpus and then `word_tokenize` to tokenize the sentences and then extract the sentences with "could":

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> corpus = " ".join(brown.words())
>>> [i for i in sent_tokenize(corpus) if u"could" in word_tokenize(i)]
```

To get the sentence before and after:

```
>>> sentences = sent_tokenize(corpus)
>>> [" ".join([sentences[i-1], j, sentences[i+1]]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences) if u"could" in word_tokenize(j)]
```

Comment: how is using NLTK splitter better than `split('. ')`?

Comment: `len(sent_tokenize('Dr. Ken works at the the hospital')) == 1`

Comment: `len('Dr. Ken works at the the hospital'.split('. ')) == 2`

Comment: Thanks! so is NLTK better because it has a lot *more* careful rules/conditions that it has extracted after going through a large database? and are these rules hard-coded or learnt ?